# Delphi Compiler expect [ on index of call of TStringsGrid cols(TStrings) property

Tags: delphi, tstringgrid

Dear Stack overflow Community

I just resently started to learn delphi. I  tried to  get the Index of a Colum  in a TString Grid over the display name. For that i  tried to call the  indexof method  on the cols property of the grid  but the Compiler give me out this

```
[dcc32 Fehler] Unit2.pas(30): E2029 '[' erwartet, aber '.' gefunden
```

as he would only allow indexed  calls  but that would litteraly beat the sense of Indexof witch is made vor the case the index is maybe each time different or could change in the future. It would be nice if somebody could point out where i went wrong. thanks in advance

here  the full code

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Grids;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    StringGrid1.Cols.IndexOf('Test');
end;

end.
```

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, you're trying to find the column that has `Test` in the header row. If so, you need to search the row instead. Something like `i := StringGrid1.Rows[0].IndexOf('Test');` should work. If `i` is greater than `-1`, it's the column that you want.

Comment: If you [read the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Grids.TStringGrid), the [`Cols` property](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Grids.TStringGrid.Cols) is not itself a `TStrings`, which is why `Cols.IndexOf()` fails to compile. The `Cols` property *returns* a `TStrings` representing a given column at a specific index.

Comment: meaning as feared that index of is pretty much useless on thtat property(if  i already knew the index i do not need the index of method)  but i do not really get the difference though the docu  says tht the type is Tstrings  like cols[index:integer]:Tsrings  if it is beacuase of an return value the compiler should  not stop me just let me fail in runtime if it was called wrong

Comment: @Ken White sry you were first to help but as i can not mark your answer s the right one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to find the index of the column with the header text 'Test', you can do so with `Rows[0].IndexOf('Test')`, assuming the header is stored in row 0.